# MINA 2.0.7 sometimes fail to notify on session closed

Tags: java, nio, mina

I have this code running:

```
logger.trace("Idle command timeout for command " + tag + " ; closing connection");
session.close(true);
```

But this code failed to run:

```
private static class Handler extends IoHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) throws Exception {
        ImapClient client = (ImapClient) session.getAttribute(ClientKey);

        connectionLogger.trace("Session closed");
        logger.trace("Session closed");
```

This only happens some of the time, and has happened since upgrading to MINA 2.0.7 from MINA 2.0.4.  Probably a bug, but any idea how to debug this or isolate it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you also override *exceptionCaught* to ensure that you're not missing a forced close on exception.

http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/service/IoHandlerAdapter.html

Comment: Quite possibly the right answer, but I don't own this code base anymore ;)